# Where to find permission for API from microsoft powershell sample

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-intune

I am trying to create a app that basically uses Win32_Application_Add.ps1 from the powershell intune samples.
The application has the following permissions:

- DeviceManagementApps.Read.All
- DeviceManagementApps.ReadWrite.All

All goes well with multiple api calls until it hits [line 1052](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/blob/c0a18f279c70be7c812669b1512808c2c1cc667e/LOB_Application/Win32_Application_Add.ps1#L1052) and i get error saying
`Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).`
I expected the app had all access it needed and would continue

The uri it calls is:

`/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}/microsoft.graph.win32LobApp/contentVersions/1/files/{fileId}`

If i use the microsoft graph explorer with my admin user it returns a valid result

**question:**

What permission is needed and how do i find that documented for this call
`/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{mobileAppId}/microsoft.graph.win32LobApp/contentVersions/1/files/{fileId}`

**what have i tried:**

I checked the function in graph explorer that will show you what permission that is needed , but it crashes the graph explorer.(function is in preview)

Tried to give the app all the [intune permission scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/developer/intune-graph-apis#intune-permission-scopes), but that had zero effect

Googling the call has not given my anything useful yet

Answer (score 0):

To check both delegated and application permissions for the Intune please refer this document, [Intune device management permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#delegated-permissions-35.).

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to reply.
I have checked that page before,
as i understand it i would need DeviceManagementApps.Read.All, but i still get 401.